# How do I fix this Boolean Problem?

Tags: modifiers

I'm trying to make a recreation of the BioShock title card from the trailer, and I'm trying to make the Indents behind the titlecard.

I created curves and snapped them to the proper positions, and then I added thickness to them. I then converted them to Mesh and tried to Boolean them in.

When I did this, half of the title card disappeared. What did I do wrong?[image]